# How to remove this type of quotes “” instead of this type of quote "" in Java?

Tags: java, string

To remove quotation marks in Java,I understand I can use

```
replaceAll("\"", "");
```

Ex: "Hello World" becomes Hello World.

However, it only removes this type of quotation marks "". Is there a way to remove quotes like this “Hello World” ?

Answer (score 3):

If you simply want to remove those 3 kinds of double-quotes, irrespective of the context:

```
replaceAll("[\"“”]", "");
```

If there are other kinds of quote characters that you want to remove, just add them before the `]`.

These pages list some of the other quote characters that you might encounter:

- https://unicode-table.com/en/sets/quotation-marks/
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark

And also see:

- [Is there a regex to grab all quotation marks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46191617/)

which talks about the difficulty in creating a regex to match *all* of them in a future-proof fashion.

Note that since we are including some "funky" characters (non-ASCII) in the source code (above), it is important that the Java compiler is aware of the character encoding that the source code uses.  We could avoid that by using Unicode escapes instead.  For example:

```
replaceAll("[\"\u201c\u201d]", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try a regex replacement here, e.g.

```java
String input = "“Hello World”";
System.out.println(input.replaceAll("“(.*?)”", "$1"));  // prints Hello World
```